# How to read only a few words or numbers from a file?

Tags: c++

I want to read from a file only the variables that matter, for example I have a `contacts.txt` and it says something like:

```
Name Penelope Pasaft
Cel 1535363236
```

and the only things I want to read or save at memory at specific variables for example the variable `name` and `cel` are the data that really matters.

In this case, I want to save `Penelope Pasaft` to the variable name and the specific number given to the variable `cel`.

In C, I used to use something like `scanf("Name %s",name)` but in C++, I don't know if there is something like that or how to do it!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) what have you tried? Please look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider your `contacts.txt` is as follows:

```
Name Penelope Pasaft
Cel 1535363236
Name David Beckam
Cel 6354562234
```

Then, the following code will produce the output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int main() {
ifstream readFromFile("contacts.txt");

string name;
string Cel;
string line;
int count = 0;
if (readFromFile.is_open()) {
    while(!readFromFile.eof()) {
    (count==2)?count=0:count=count;
        getline(readFromFile, line, ' ');
            if(line == "Name") {
            getline(readFromFile, name, '\n');
            ++ count;
            } else if(line == "Cel") {
                getline(readFromFile, Cel, '\n');
            count ++;
            }

    if(count==2) {
        cout<<"Name: "<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Cel: "<<Cel<<endl;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Output will be as follows:

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
$ ./a.out
Name: Penelope Pasaft
Cel: 1535363236
Name: David Beckam
Cel: 6354562234
```

Comment: @Arya - Please try as mentioned in the whole code and please accept the answer if it is working.

Comment: You should not loop using `eof()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong